# VBA - Close window

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates 17 workbooks in a loop. When it's done working on a workbook it closes it and goes to the next with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
```

This has always worked fine until recently. Suddenly on loop nr. 7 it say (the 6 loops before still working fine):

> Run-time '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Method 'Close' of objekt 'Window' failed

I can delete "ActiveWindow.Close" and close all the workbooks manually to make the macro work. But still...

Any knows why it does this?

Comment: It can be related to language settings, have you added any languages or fonts recently? Or upgraded with a Service Pack? [Here's](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-80010108-errors.html) a page that talks about some of the possibilities, but depends on what your code is doing.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a wait period?

Comment: do you mean "creates 17 *workbooks* in a loop" ?

Comment: at iDevlop - Yes.  at Remou - no, I can Try. Thanks

Comment: Edited to reflect this and avoid confusion.

Comment: Nice one, Remou. Put it as an answer so David can accept it and other users can find the solution if they are having the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per comment.

A wait period may solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you are using ActiveWindow.Close, perhaps that has something to do with it. The proper way to close a book (as far as I know) is:

```
Workbooks(excelFile).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Sometimes some wacky things happen when refering to the active object, so it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I use the number of the window... i.e. I know this will be Window #1, so I refer to it that way. Example:

```
Windows(1).Close SaveChanges:=False
```